# What is this spiky-leaved Mexican plant with large seed pods?

Tags: food-identification

Is this plant edible? Location: Mexico

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about [plant identification that involve "is this edible" are off topic here](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/33128). We only identify known-edible food items. [gardening.se] will likely be happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be some sort of [Agave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agave) genus of succulent plants, like Sisal or Blue Agave from which Tequila is distilled. Not sure which species exactly, perhaps [Agave Lechuguilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agave_lechuguilla)

The fruit bearing trunk visible in the photo appears to be a blooming stalk.

<sup>[Source](https://keyserver.lucidcentral.org/weeds/data/media/Html/agave_angustifolia.htm)</sup>

[image]

[Parts of some plants are edible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agave#Uses), like leaves, flowers and stalks, but the fruit doesn't seem to be suited for human consumption, as far as I know.

From what I gather around the internet they mostly seems like bean pods and contains little more than what appear to be seeds.

<sup>[Source](https://everythingisnotblackandwhite.com/blog/?m=201510)</sup>

[image]

<sup>[Source](https://penstemon.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/agave-fruit-5.jpg)</sup>

[image]